# Expo json5 issue: Why is npm audit fix --force not resolving the vulnerability?

Tags: reactjs, expo, native

npm audit

## npm audit report

```bash
json5  <1.0.2
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution in JSON5 via Parse Method - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9c47-m6qq-7p4h
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install expo@1.0.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/babel-preset-expo/node_modules/json5
  find-babel-config  <=1.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of json5
  node_modules/babel-preset-expo/node_modules/find-babel-config
    babel-plugin-module-resolver  2.3.0 - 4.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of find-babel-config
    node_modules/babel-preset-expo/node_modules/babel-plugin-module-resolver
      babel-preset-expo  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-module-resolver
      node_modules/babel-preset-expo
        expo  >=14.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-preset-expo
        node_modules/expo

5 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

```bash
├─┬ @babel/core@7.20.12
│ └── json5@2.2.3 deduped
├─┬ @expo/json-file@8.2.35 extraneous
│ └── json5@1.0.2 extraneous
├─┬ babel-plugin-module-resolver@2.5.0 invalid: "5.0.0" from the root project
│ └─┬ find-babel-config@1.2.0
│   └── json5@0.5.1
├─┬ expo-splash-screen@0.17.5 extraneous
│ └─┬ @expo/prebuild-config@5.0.7
│   └─┬ @expo/json-file@8.2.36
│     └── json5@1.0.2
├─┬ expo@47.0.13
│ ├─┬ @expo/cli@0.4.11
│ │ ├─┬ @expo/json-file@8.2.36
│ │ │ └── json5@1.0.2
│ │ ├─┬ @expo/metro-config@0.5.2
│ │ │ └─┬ @expo/json-file@8.2.36
│ │ │   └── json5@1.0.2
│ │ └─┬ @expo/package-manager@0.0.57
│ │   └─┬ @expo/json-file@8.2.36
│ │     └── json5@1.0.2
│ ├─┬ @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
│ │ └─┬ @expo/json-file@8.2.36
│ │   └── json5@1.0.2
│ ├─┬ babel-preset-expo@9.2.2
│ │ └─┬ babel-plugin-module-resolver@4.1.0
│ │   └─┬ find-babel-config@1.2.0
│ │     └── json5@0.5.1
│ └─┬ expo-constants@14.0.2
│   └─┬ @expo/config@7.0.3
│     └─┬ @expo/json-file@8.2.36
│       └── json5@1.0.2
├─┬ find-babel-config@2.0.0
│ └── json5@2.2.3 deduped
├── json5@2.2.3
└─┬ loader-utils@2.0.4 extraneous
  └── json5@2.2.3 deduped
```

"npm audit fix --force" or npm install --save json5@latest command is not working as expected.

Comment: You can try running `npm update` which will update dependent / vulnerable packages to latest version. This should fix the issue

Comment: I have tried running "npm update" and "npm install" and deleted the "node_modules" folder. However, I'm not sure if this issue is happening to everyone or if it's just happening to me because of Expo.

Comment: Same thing happening to me in a new install. I think the new version of expo 48 is buggy.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `package-lock.json` and find:

```
"node_modules/find-babel-config": {
    "version": "1.2.0",
    "resolved": "...",
    "integrity": "...",
    "dependencies": {
        "json5": "^0.5.1", // Here is the problem
        "path-exists": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=4.0.0"
    }
},
```

2. Change to `"json5": "^2.2.3"` and run `npm install`

This solve the problem but still the npm audit will show high severity report

To fix that find and change this:

```
"node_modules/find-babel-config/node_modules/json5": {
    "version": "0.5.1",
    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/json5/-/json5-0.5.1.tgz",
}
```

To:

```
"node_modules/find-babel-config/node_modules/json5": {
    "version": "^2.2.3",
    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/json5/-/json5-2.2.3.tgz",
}
```

Then run `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

resolved issues by updating the dependencies in the package-lock.json file, not user if this is the best scenario. I followed the steps on this website: https://itnext.io/fixing-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-dependencies-in-less-than-3-mins-a53af735261d

The issues looks like a false positive.

Check the version of the packages installed. You can either remove the dep